# Nullspace dimension of row vector $u^\intercal$ is $n-1$-dimensional, but formula is not $n \times n-1$

Tags: linear-algebra

I learned about the $\mathcal{R}$-range and $\mathcal{N}$-null spaces. A question emerged during my learning:

why do not-null row vectors $u^\intercal \in \mathbb{R}^n$ has an $n \times n$ orthogonal  matrix $I - \frac{u u^\intercal}{u^\intercal u}$, instead of $n \times (n-1)$?

It does not seem critical, since it is a well-known result, but it makes my gears grind.